# Run sub module tests w/ mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have a project that contains sub modules and the sub modules contain tests:

```
project
---> submodule1/
        package.json
        test/submodule1Test.js
---> submodule2/
        package.json
        test/submodule2Test.js
package.json
test/projectTest.js
```

When I run mocha it will run everything under the main project test folder (ie projectTest.js).  However it does not run the tests for the submodules.  I don't expect that would work out of the box, but is there a good way to run those tests everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [in the usage docs](http://mochajs.org/#usage) you can pass a list of file paths or [globs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). If you don't, it assumes `./test/*.js` as default. In your case, this should suffice:

```
mocha ./**/test/**/*.js
```

If you want to avoid typing it, you can save it to the `mocha.opts` file. Its contents in this case would be simply

```
./**/test/**/*.js
```

Now you can run just `mocha` and get the same result.

Comment: Sorry I was wondering more about is there a way I make the mocha command do something like that by default.  Point being is that I will remember to run it that way but others who come into my baseline may not.

Comment: Running `mocha` or `mocha ./**/test/**/*.js` is arbitrary.
However, you can use the mocha.opts file to set it as "default". I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks so much for your help!